# Nextjs 13 HIPAA Compliant Tech Stack

Tags: web, next.js

I am currently creating a web application for a medical company. All the data needs to be stored on a HIPAA compliant database, and deployed to a HIPAA compliant web hosting service. (HIPAA compliance is the standard for sensitive patient data protection that all companies dealing with protected health information (PHI) must follow). Any tech stack suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to Next.js, unfortunately Vercel is NOT HIPAA compliant, but AWS Amplify seems to be the best option for hosting a Next.js application.

Supabase is a great option to handle auth / postgres db / storage all in one, and they just became HIPAA compliant, but in order to have HIPAA compliance built in you must be on their teams plan ($600/month).  Otherwise AWS will probably be your go to solution for all the backend services as well.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Vercel is HIPAA compliant, but post is not dated unfortunately

https://vercel.com/guides/is-vercel-hipaa-compliant

Answer (score 0):

To comply with the HIPAA Security Rule, all covered entities must do the following:

- Ensure the confidentiality, integrity, and availability of all electronic protected health information
- Detect and safeguard against anticipated threats to the security of the information
- Protect against anticipated impermissible uses or disclosures
- Certify compliance by their workforce.

So it seems that you need to implement some basic security standards and the stack itself does not really matter that much, as long as you can provide the above requirements.

---

You can find more information about the specific compliance guidelines [here](https://www.hhs.gov/sites/default/files/ocr/privacy/hipaa/administrative/securityrule/techsafeguards.pdf?language=en)